# httpClientConfigurerRef for Apache Camel for specific routes

Tags: apache-camel

Lets say that I want to communicate to a rest service with SSL with Camel, and I'm creating a [custom HttpClientConfigurer](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Fuse_Mediation_Router/2.6/html/Component_Reference/files/_IDU_HTTP.html) which will set that stuff:

```
<bean id="myHttpClientConfigurer"
 class="my.https.HttpClientConfigurer">
</bean>

<to uri="https://myhostname.com:443/myURL?httpClientConfigurerRef=myHttpClientConfigurer"/>
```

And the HttpClientConfigurer implements `org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpClientConfigurer`.

So my question is, will this custom HttpClientConfigurer will be active for only that route (where I specify it with httpClientConfigurerRef)? Or will it affect other Camel routes that use the http component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for that route. Always test and verify! Fire up a second route without it and you should observe that the second route does not handle the SSL handshake.